# Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component when using Create React App and Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik, react-forms

Im getting this error and I seriously dont know what Im doing wrong. The program worked just fine a few hours ago. This only began happening after I installed Formik but everything looks okay to me. Here's the code:

```
import React from "react";
import { useFormik } from "formik";

export default function YoutubeForm() {
    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            name: "",
            email: "",
            channel: "",
        },
    });

    console.log("formik values", formik.values);

    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    id="name"
                    name="name"
                    onChange={formik.handleChange}
                    value={formik.values.name}
                />

                <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                <input
                    type="email"
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    onChange={formik.handleChange}
                    value={formik.values.email}
                />

                <label htmlFor="channel">Channel</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    id="channel"
                    name="channel"
                    onChange={formik.handleChange}
                    value={formik.values.channel}
                />

                <button>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Can somebody please explain to me why this is happening

I get this when I run "npm ls react":

├─┬ @testing-library/react@12.1.2
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ react-dom@17.0.2
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ react-scripts@5.0.0
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
└── react@17.0.2

I'm not really sure what any of this means

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I did this:

```
// Add this in node_modules/react-dom/index.js
window.React1 = require('react');

// Add this in your component file
require('react-dom');
window.React2 = require('react');
console.log(window.React1 === window.React2);
```

and it logged out "false" which could mean that my app is using two Reacts

Comment: Your code looks fine. Probably there is some other code that causes that behavior https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-boyd-hnc3d?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Can you share with us full code example?

Comment: @jkaczmarkiewicz this is the entire code. According to the React docs, this app might be using more than one copy of the React package. If this is the case, how could I possibly resolve it without deleting everything and starting afresh?

Comment: How your package.json looks like?

Comment: @jkaczmarkiewicz sorry about that. Just edited the question. It should be there now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see `formik` package installed. Try to install it

```
npm i formik
```

It might be because you have `formik` installed globally

Next, please delete `node-modules` and `package-lock.json` and then please run `npm i`

Comment: Turns out I installed formik in a different directory and didn't realise it. Thank you for the help. It works now